# Mongoid dynamic query

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

This must be an easy one, but I'm stuck...
So I'm using Rails#3 with Mongoid and want to dynamically build query that would depend upon passed parameters and **then** execute find().
Something like

```
def select_posts
    query = :all # pseudo-code here
    if (params.has_key?(:author))
        query += where(:author => params[:author]) # this is pseudo-code again
    end

    if (params.has_key?(:post_date))
        query += where(:create_date => params[:post_date]) # stay with me
    end

    @post_bodies = []
    Post.find(query).each do |post| # last one
        @post_bodies << post.body
    end

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.json { render :json => @post_bodies }
    end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a few different options to go with here - depending on how complex your actual application is going to get. Using your example directly - you could end up with something like:

```
query = Post.all
query = query.where(:author => params[:author]) if params.has_key?(:author)
query = query.where(:create_date => params[:post_date]) if params.has_key?(:post_date)
@post_bodies = query.map{|post| post.body}
```

Which works because queries (Criteria) in Mongoid are chainable.

---

Alternatively, if you're going to have lots more fields that you wish to leverage, you could do the following:

```
query = Post.all
fields = {:author => :author, :post_date => :create_date}
fields.each do |params_field, model_field|
  query = query.where(model_field => params[params_field]) if params.has_key?(params_field)
end
@post_bodies = query.map{|post| post.body}
```

---

And finally, you can take it one level further and properly nest your form parameters, and name the parameters so that they match with your model, so that your `params` object looks something like this:

```
params[:post] = {:author => "John Smith", :create_date => "1/1/1970", :another_field => "Lorem ipsum"}
```

Then you could just do:

```
@post_bodies = Post.where(params[:post]).map{|post| post.body}
```

Of course, with that final example, you'd want to sanitize the input fields - to prevent malicious users from tampering with the behaviour.

Comment: Hi

i did like this 


      query = ''
      params[:event].each do |key, value|      
          query += "{#{key}: #{value.to_s}}," if value.present? 
      end
    events = Event.or(query)


But is is not working in MONGOID... can you please help